# Return SQL rows between from_date and to_date regardless of year in SQL only matching day and month not year

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and it has a column `start_date`. I have two variable fields/filters `from_date` and `to_date` on which I want my records to be filtered.

I am working on a SQL/PostgreSQL/pgAdmin4 script that returns all the rows whose `start_date` is between `from_date` and `to_date` only matching day and month (not year). For example: let's say `from_date` is '2023-12-25' and `to_date` is '2023-02-07'. I want to get all the rows where the `start_date` lies between these dates regardless of the year.

So, it will return rows falling between 25th Dec and 7th Feb. Thanks in advance.

I have checked this answer [In SQL how to return records matching date and month only (ignore year)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6421609/11537066)

and tried the same with the query:

and tried the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
WHERE status = 'Active'
AND (
    (
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM from_date::DATE) <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date::DATE) 
        AND (TO_CHAR(start_date::date, 'MM/DD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(from_date::date, 'MM/DD') AND TO_CHAR(to_date::date, 'MM/DD'))
    ) 
    OR (
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM from_date::DATE) > EXTRACT(MONTH FROM to_date::DATE) 
        AND (
            (TO_CHAR(start_date::date, 'MM/DD') BETWEEN TO_CHAR(from_date::date, 'MM/DD') AND '31/12')
            OR (TO_CHAR(start_date::date, 'MM/DD') BETWEEN '01/01' AND TO_CHAR(to_date::date, 'MM/DD'))
        )
    )
);
```

but not getting any data

Comment: Please share sample data, expected result and what you have tried

Comment: It's ugly, but something like this could work extract(month from start_date)*100 + extract(day from start_date) between
extract(month from from_date)*100 + extract(day from from_date) and 
extract(month from to_date)*100 + extract(day from to_date)

Comment: typo - 'let's say from_date is '2023-12-25' and from_date is '2023-02-07'.' - should be let's say from_date is '2023-12-25' and to_date is '2024-02-07' ?

Comment: "not getting any data" is because of the `start_date`, see first query in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zMJTBAsh) which does not return data, and second query does return data (but everything, and not selection...)

Comment: @Luuk, how can I fix this? pls help me out

Comment: @Sheraram_Prajapat: Please take a look at my answer, and feel free to post comments (when needed) 

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```sql
select *
from table_name
where
  date_part('doy', start_date) between date_part('doy', from_date) and date_part('doy', to_date)
```

This will use the numerical version of the day of the year as the comparison between the given dates.

You might need to swap `from_date` and `to_date` around as I've taken `to_date` to be the later date.

See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date-functions/postgresql-date_part/ for more date parts you can use with `date_part`.

EDIT: To account for the discrepancies of leap years try this

```sql
select id
from table_name
where
  (
    date_part('month', start_date) < date_part('month', to_date) and
    date_part('month', start_date) > date_part('month', from_date)
  ) or
  (
    date_part('month', from_date) < date_part('month', to_date) and
    date_part('month', start_date) = date_part('month', to_date) and
    date_part('day', to_date) > date_part('day', start_date)
  ) or
  (
    date_part('month', from_date) < date_part('month', to_date) and
    date_part('month', start_date) = date_part('month', from_date) and
    date_part('day', from_date) < date_part('day', start_date)
  ) or
  (
    date_part('month', from_date) = date_part('month', to_date) and
    date_part('month', start_date) = date_part('month', from_date) and
    date_part('day', from_date) < date_part('day', to_date) and
    date_part('day', start_date) between date_part('day', from_date) and date_part('day', to_date)
  )
```

Comment: Careful with this. Say the start_date is 2023-06-10, to_date is 2023-07-01, from_date is 2023-05-15.

Comment: @Error_2646 I know, that's why I added the caveat saying I'd taken `to_date` to be the earlier date (as they did in their example). They're free to swap around `from_date` and `to_date`, depending on which will be the lower bound

Comment: Same point still applies. start_date 2023-06-10, to_date is 2023-05-09, from_date is 2023-07-01 .

Comment: This can't give you the correct result when there are leap years involved. The first of March doesn't have the same day-of-year number for each year. Better to extract the month and the day, that will give you the correct results.

Comment: @Error_2646 I'm afraid I'm not understanding the point you're trying to make. So are you saying that the solution should account for cases where `to_date > from_date` and `from_date > to_date`?

Comment: @B.Griffin More that you shouldn't compare the date parts piecewise. Like Frank said, and similar to my suggestion in the question body, the comparison needs account for the month. Because 2023-06-01 > 2023-05-31, and 2023-06-30 < 2023-07-01. The day by itself isn't enough.

Comment: @B.Griffin Ah, my bad. Didn't see that you were using 'doy' instead of 'day'.

Answer (score 0):

I created this, which seems to work:

```
with recursive d as (
    select 
        '2023-12-31'::DATE as startdate,
        '2023-12-25'::DATE as fromdate,
        '2023-02-07'::DATE as todate
  ),
fromto as (
select 
   startdate,
   fromdate,
   todate,
   case when startdate>=fromdate then extract(month from fromdate) else extract(month from todate) end as month_from2,
   case when startdate>=fromdate then extract(day from fromdate) else extract(day from todate) end as day_from2,
   case when startdate>=fromdate then extract(month from todate) else extract(month from fromdate) end as month_to2,
   case when startdate>=fromdate then extract(day from todate) else extract(day from fromdate) end as day_to2
from d
),
dates as (
   select '2022-01-01'::DATE as d
   union all
   select (d+INTERVAL '1 day')::DATE from dates where d<'2025-01-01'::date
   )
select * 
from dates
cross join fromto
where case when startdate>=fromdate 
      then (extract(month from d)>month_from2 or (extract(month from d)=month_from2 and extract(day from d)>=day_from2))
            or (extract(month from d)<month_to2 or (extract(month from d)=month_to2 and extract(day from d)<=day_to2))
      else (extract(month from d)>month_from2 or (extract(month from d)=month_from2 and extract(day from d)>=day_from2))
            and (extract(month from d)<month_to2 or (extract(month from d)=month_to2 and extract(day from d)<=day_to2))
     end
;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/j1kXPzCC)

- The CTE `d` contains the values like `startdate`, `fromdate` and `todate`
- The CTE `fromto` calculates some variables used in the final statement
- The CTE `dates` creates a list of all the dates from '2022-01-01' to '2025-01-01'
- The final SQL statement contains pretty standard SQL stuff, and does not need more explanation (IMHO )